# Dragon-like creature trying to find another creature like itself

Tags: story-identification, books

I can't remember a book and I really want to know what it is. I read it when I was young and I loved it. I think on the book there was a dragon or something and he was traveling by himself to find another dragon or creature like him.

Also in another part of the story when he was traveling there was this creature that could change into what other creatures looked like and it changed into the dragon and almost killed it.

I also think that in the story there was a huge tree that in the roots of it held 7 elements or something like that. I'm not sure if that's the same book but it might be. Please help!!

Comment: I'd suggest to be a bit more precise in the title and adding the tag story-identification

Comment: What years were you young/what year did you read this story?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to suggest *[Merlin's Dragon](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3148116-merlin-s-dragon)*, a spin-off from T.A. Barron's *Lost Years of Merlin* series. It follows Basilgarrad, a rare sort of dragon who contains all seven elements of the roots of Avalon.

> In the years after Fincayra disappears and Merlin has been sent wandering, a young lizard-like creature, with the wings of a bat and the magical power to produce any smell it encounters, is born into the new world of Avalon. The unlikely hero—Basil, he is called—cannot find a single creature like itself nor a person who can tell him what he is. But it is clear that Basil is much more than he seems when he stumbles into an encounter with the great Merlin, saving his child’s life, then uncovers a secret plot by the evil Rhita Gawr. It’s a race against time and across Avalon as Basil, with the help of the faithful wind sister Ailah, searches for the great wizard to warn him.

[image]

One detail that might help nail it for you, Basil can "cast smells" (not a typo), being able to replicate any smell he's ever experienced.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102910/story-involving-a-young-merlin (about "Lost Years of Merlin" series)

Answer (score 1):

That sounds a lot like The Last Unicorn, but it isn't a dragon that is trying to find its way. It's a unicorn. There are creatures that look like other creatures when she stumbles upon a wizard with his troupe of traveling bandits who are creating illusions to trick honest people out of their money. The evil witch in the troupe has a real harpy though that attacks them. The end of what you say doesn't fit, although she does turn into a human, and the bull (main villain) is still a cloven hoofed creature. So it kind of fits, but not exactly. There is also a tree in it that is... interesting. The tree doesn't have anything to do with elements, but it does come to life. I'm pretty sure this isn't it, but I thought it may help you remember something.

https://d.gr-assets.com/books/1217313735l/917220.jpg